# Function to change object.object properties

Tags: javascript

I'm Trying to work with some objects here and want a simple read/write function for it.

My object will contain more objects so the problem is in acessing the child objects properties. I can read it simple enough, but when I try to change the property value I only change the functions varible target so it no longer points to the object.

```
var OBJ = {
    name:"",
    obj2:
    {
        name:"Test",
        something:"text"
    }
};

function readFromObject(target){
    console.log(target);
}

function writeToObject(target,val){
    target = val;
    // More code
}
readFromObject(OBJ.obj2.name);
writeToObject(OBJ.obj2.name,"newVal");
readFromObject(OBJ.obj2.name);
```

Hopefully someone gets what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `OBJ.obj2.name = "newVal";` ?

Comment: What is the interest of doing `writeToObject(OBJ.obj2.name,"newVal");` instead of `OBJ.obj2.name = "newVal"` ? When you give `OBJ.obj2.name` as parameter, you only give the string value of the name field. Only the value, not the reference.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve makes no sense to me. Why would you want to type more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like you simply want to make a generic setter and a generic getter.

You can do it like this :

```
function readFromObject(obj, property) {
    console.log(obj[property]);
}

function writeToObject(obj, property, value) {
    obj[property] = value;
    // More code
}

readFromObject(OBJ.obj2, 'name');
writeToObject(OBJ.obj2, 'name', 'newVal');
readFromObject(OBJ.obj2, 'name');
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use this instead of just write `OBJ.obj2['name'] = 'newVal';`

Comment: It does make sense. It's like a simple setter. Sometimes you want to do some code everytime you change a value in an object. Just replace `// More code` by what you want.

Comment: Okay I got the point now, but still OPs question is terrible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats perfect. And like Magus said, I'll be doing some stuff each time the object changes.